# Prestashop change indexation function

Tags: php, regex, prestashop

In my shop I've got product with name for example: ***VANS AUTHENTIC LITE Z5J187*** and when I'm searching for ***vans*** or ***authentic*** or ***lite*** I've the results. But when I'm trying to search for ***Z5J187*** I'm getting no results.

I've figured it out that in the database there's a table `ps_search_word` with words that are used for search. I've noticed that there are words like: ***vans***, ***authentic*** etc. but not ***Z5J187*** and any other code like this.

In `Search.php` class file there are declared variables like `PREG_CLASS_SEARCH_EXCLUDE, PREG_CLASS_NUMBERS, PREG_CLASS_PUNCTUATION`. When I've cleared the `PREG_CLASS_NUMBERS` and Re-build the entire index in the table `ps_search_word` there are new words and there was some of the products codes but not all, but also there was no ***vans***, ***nike*** etc. words.

What should I change so the idexation puts also my product codes into table `ps_search_word`?

Comment: This seems like more of an SQL question than a regex question

Comment: Which prestashop version you are using?

Comment: From experience, at least some versions of Prestashop have bugs in the search indexation. We wrote the search function to not use the indexation. I know it's not advised due to performance, but at least finds all products. If you don't have a large number of products you could try to include those words in the product tags.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this problem on prestashop.

on this website :

https://piltanshop.com

serch these words:

PTT201

520DS

My guess is this:

You probably changed the product name after indexing

Solution:

on BO, goto Preferences>>search and reindex all